# Read from a file then convert from to int?

Tags: c++

I wrote this function that is supposed to read from a file containing ACII decimal numbers and convert these to integers stored in an int array. Here is that function:

```
void readf1()
{
    int myintArray[100];
    int i = 0;
    int result;
    string line = "";
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("f1.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()){
      //while not end of file
      while(!myfile.eof()){
        //get the line
        getline(myfile, line);

        /* PROBLEM HERE */
        result = atoi(line);

        myintArray[i] = result;
        //myintArray[i]
        cout<<"Read in the number: "<<myintArray[i]<<"\n\n";
        i++;
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is that atoi is not working. The error I get is `cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'`. I'm not sure why its not working as I looked at examples and I am using it exactly the same. Anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you `cout << line` and post what it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`atoi` is a C function that accepts a C-string, not a C++ `std::string`. You need to obtain the raw `char*` from the string object to use as the argument. The method for this is `.c_str()`:

> ```
> atoi(line.c_str());
> ```

The C++ equivalent of `atoi` is [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (C++11):

> ```
> std::stoi(line);
> ```

Moreover, `while (!file.eof())` is considered a bad practice. It's better to do the I/O operation inside the expression so the stream object is returned and valid file conditions are assessed thereafter:

> ```
> while (std::getline(myfile, line))
> ```

Your code can be improved further, however. Here is how I would do it:

> ```
> #include <vector>
>
> void readf1()
> {
>     std::vector<int> myintArray;
>
>     std::string line;
>     std::ifstream myfile("f1.txt");
>
>     for (int result; std::getline(myfile, line); result = std::stoi(line))
>     {
>         myintArray.push_back(result);
>
>         std::cout << "Read in the number: " << result << "\n\n";
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Not only did you answer my question but provided improved code and showed better habits to practice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`atoi()` wants a `char *`, not a `string`:

```
result = atoi(line.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
result = atoi(line.c_str());
```